# How to create a static library using Makefile.ios in rubber band project

Tags: ios, objective-c, command-line, makefile, rubber-band

I need to create a static library from this repo https://bitbucket.org/breakfastquay/rubberband.

It does include Makefile.ios but I do not know how to create a static library using this Makefile.ios

Does anyone know how to create a static library from the above repo ?

Note: I tried to use this repo (https://github.com/hasseily/Makefile-to-iOS-Framework) to execute the Makefile.ios but so far no luck creating a static library from the rubber band repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I created the static library from rubber band library.

Step: 1 Download the repo from  https://bitbucket.org/breakfastquay/rubberband.

Step: 2 Install libsndfile using "brew install libsndfile" without quotes

Step: 3 Install command line tools for Xcode using "xcode-select --install" without quotes

Step: 4 create a folder name lib inside the repository folder you have download

Step: 5 use the "make -f Makefile.ios" command to create the static library

After that you can find the static library inside the lib folder